# Average number of cores and memory used per namespace in K8s?

Tags: kubernetes

Need to calculate the average number of cores and memory used over a period of time (like say a month) for a particular namespace in K8s, how can we go about doing this?

We want to calculate the cost for each namespace, we did try the Kubecost tool in AKS, but it didn't match the cost shown on the Azure Cost dashboard, in fact, it was way more than the actual cost.

Comment: Do you monitor your Kubernetes cluster with Prometheus ? 
If so, you can probably use PromQL queries to find CPU and memory used in the last week/month etc.

Comment: @matt_j yes we do have prometheus, thanks will check around.